# Help me with understanding the meaning of "apparent" in this sentence

Tags: meaning

There are reasons for denying that the relationship between recalled sensations and sensory imagery are what is responsible for apparent possibility of imagined sensations.

Comment: Did you look *apparent* up in a dictionary? If you did, tell us what you didn't understand about the definition.

Comment: @Daniel is right. I'll note too that for all its academician pomp and bluster, that sentence us ungrammatical. *The relationship* ***are***?

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the source for this sentence, so I will guess what was written in that passage. The article was likely discussing the phenomena of imagined sensations.The article may now be positing that the relationship between recalled sensations and sensory imagery may not be the cause of those imagined sensations.

These imagined sensations are an "apparent possibility", that is, the passage is not presently confirming or denying their existence. It is merely stating that as per the evidence brought above, these sensations "would appear to exist", in other words, there is some proof that these sensations may exist.

Comment: Add some line breaks plz.